# Can I check for the availability of standard Unix shell utilities

Tags: shell, unix, cmake

I want to run a bash script as part of my build configuration; and it uses some standard unix utilities, e.g. `mkdir`, `egrep`, `sed`... can I check, using CMake and at once, that all "typical" Unix utilities are present on my system?

Comment: As for '*all "typical" Unix utilities*', I find this group quite vague, and I don't expect CMake to have a ready-made check for it. Concerning your specific examples, I don't find useful to check `mkdir` existence, which is part of some core package (e.g. [coreutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/coreutils/filelist) on Ubuntu) without which almost no "normal" program could work. `grep` and `sed` packages are installed on most machines too, but you could check them via `find_program` for allow a user to redefine the default utility with the one providing specific features.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check, it can be done in the script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

chk_cmd() {
    command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "Command '$1' not found"
}

die() {
    echo "$*" >&2
    exit 1
}

chk_cmd mkdir
mkdir -p /path/to/new/dir 

chk_cmd grep
if grep -Eq "$pattern" "$file"; then ...
```

Comment: That's not a bad option, but - the script may not be run at build configuration time.